# UITextField delegate methods not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, delegates, ios7

So I have a series of text fields in cells of a UITableView that lives within a UIViewController (not table view controller). I can edit the text fields, but the delegate methods like - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField are not getting called.

The view controller has its delegate set:

```
@interface NRSignUpViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

The fields are declared:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *lastName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *email;
```

and delegates are set in viewDidLoad:

```
_firstName.delegate = self;
_lastName.delegate = self;
_email.delegate = self;
```

Here's cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)table cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [table dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

   UITextField *tf = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, table.frame.size.width-20, 30)];
   tf.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
   tf.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyNext;
   switch (indexPath.row) {
       case 0:
           tf.placeholder = @"First name";
           tf.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
           _firstName = tf;
           break;
       case 1:
           tf.placeholder = @"Last name";
           tf.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeWords;
           _lastName = tf;
           break;
       case 2:
            tf.placeholder = @"Email address";
            tf.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
           tf.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeEmailAddress;
           _email = tf;
           break;
       default:
           break;
    }

    [cell.contentView addSubview:tf];
    return cell;
}
```

Any ideas what could be missing?

Comment: For Swift: make sure the delegate methods aren't in a private extension; they can still be in a normal extension though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're setting the delegates in `viewDidLoad` but not actually creating the text fields until `cellForRow...`.

Comment: That's it - thank you! Knew it had to be something obvious that I was overlooking.

Answer (score 3):

Put a breakpoint inside your `viewDidLoad` method and check if your text fields are `nil`. That's because the object is not initialized yet. You should set the delegates inside the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, because at that point is when they are actually allocated.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can try this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
 addObserver:self
 selector:@selector(methodNothing)
 name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
 object:firstName];
```

and you can use:`UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditingNotification` or `UITextFieldTextDidEndEditingNotification`